# Error API REST MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

Buenas,

He diseñado una API Rest en NodeJS.

Funciona correctamente, pero cuando la dejo arrancada mas de 24 horas me da error de conexión en BD MySQL.

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/home/ARM/Documentos/api-rest-iof/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:113:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ARM/Documentos/api-rest-iof/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:28)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Tengo creado un modulo con la informacion de la conexion y lo llamo desde el controller de tal forma:

```
//Importamos los datos de la conexión
var conn=require('../models/connection');

//Importamos el paquete mysql
var mysql = require('mysql'),
//Creamos la conexión a nuestra base de datos con los datos almacenados en conn
connection = mysql.createConnection(
    conn
);

//funcion para comprobar si esta repetido el usuario
function getUserDB(email, done) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1', [email], function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    //console.log(rows[0]);

    console.log('usuario ya registrado' + rows[0]);
    done(rows[0]);
  });
}
```

¿Cual puede ser el problema?, un cierre de sesion de MySQL por tiempo?

Gracias y un saludo.

**EDIT1:**

He cambiado la conexion a la base de datos de tal forma:

He creado un modulo con los datos e importo ese modulo en el controller

```
var connection=require('../models/connection');
//Coger todos los usuarios
function usuariosfull(req, res) {
        if (connection)
        {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios', function(err, rows) {
                if(err)
                {
                    throw err;
                    console.log('Error al Conectar' + error);
                }
                else
                {
            res.status(200).json(rows);
                }
            });
        }
            connection.end();

}
```

Al realizar el cierre de la conexión lógicamente se cierra y cuando intento llamar a otro método de la API me dice:

```
OPTIONS http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3790/api/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Que entiendo que es lo lógico ya que has cerrado y la conexión se arranca al iniciar la API,

¿Donde tengo que poner el cierre de conexión?.

En estos momentos estoy lanzando mi API con `npm start`. Es posible que sea por esto el problema y por no tener un servicio desplegado?

Gracias de nuevo.

**Edit2:**

Buenas de nuevo,

He cambiado por lo que habéis mencionado, con un pool creando la conexión al llamar al método y cerrándola con el release() de conexiones.

Pero no se si es la forma correcta de hacerlo, buscando API Rest Solo realizan una conexión, mi duda es que tengo 20 metodos para la api, tengo que poner en todos la llamada pool.getConnection ?

Ejemplo:

Modulo connect:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   password: 'xxxxxxxx',
   database: 'xxxxxxxx',
   port: 3306
});

module.exports = pool;
```

Controller:

```
var pool=require('../models/connection');


//Listar todos los datos del invernadero
function getInvfull(req, res) {

  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error al pedir una conexión: '+err);
    return;
  }
  console.log("pruebas de conexion");
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios', function(err, rows) {
    if(err) {
      throw err;
      console.log('Error al ejecutar la query ' + error);
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(rows);
    }
  });
  //para que pueda ser reutilizada por el pool, es importante "liberarla"
  connection.release();
});

}
```

Comment: Puede ser que el servidor donde lo tengas alojado te cierre la conexión cada x tiempo, yo por ejemplo uso heroku para subir las app en node y si están mas de 1 hora sin nadie conectado a ellas me la cierra hasta que alguien vuelva a entrar, puede ser eso perfectamente, tu código lo veo bien

Comment: Es posible que sea por no tener un cierre en la conexion a la BD? EJ: conn.end(); @CobasESP

Comment: Intenta abrir la conexion dentro del metodo y cerrarla al finalizar el metodo. Probablemente el servidor esta cerrando la conexion por innactividad o el pool de conexiones esta lleno y mata la conexion.

Comment: Acabo de editar el POST @Einer, por si puedes eyudarme un poco. gracias

Comment: Al parecer tu problema esta en que estas iniciando la conexion en el archivo `connection`. Tienes que iniciar la conexion cuando vayas a consultar y cuando termines cerrarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar un *pool* de conexiones para gestionar automáticamente el tener siempre una conexión activa:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'guess'
});
```

Y luego usarlo para obtener las conexiones:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error al pedir una conexión: '+err);
    return;
  }
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios', function(err, rows) {
    if(err) {
      throw err;
      console.log('Error al ejecutar la query ' + error);
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(rows);
    }
  });
  //para que pueda ser reutilizada por el pool, es importante "liberarla"
  connection.release(); 
});
```

Pequeña explicación:
Al crear un pool usas las mismas opciones que al crear una única conexión, pero además puedes definir otras, como una bastante explicativa que pongo a continuación:

`connectionLimit`: El valor por defecto es 10.

¿Cómo funciona el pool? Cada vez que requieres una conexión, se la pides al pool usando `getConnection()` y éste:

- Si no existe ninguna, la creará en el momento.
- Si existe, pero está siendo usada, creará una nueva, mientras no se llegue al límite establecido con la opción `connectionLimit`.
- Si existe y no está siendo usada, entonces está disponible y te la dará.

Cuando tu método ya no necesita la conexión, la devuelves con `connection.release()`. Esto no cierra la conexión, simplemente la devuelve al pool para que la reutilice. Si la conexión "muere" porque no se usa durante mucho tiempo, pues el pool lo sabrá y creará otra cuando sea necesario.

Si te parece muy pesado y repetitivo pedir la conexión y liberarla cada vez, puedes crear un wrapper como el de esta respuesta de [StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38249713/1919228)

Comment: Buenas, antes de nada gracias por la ayuda. Acabo de editar el POST por si lo ves correcto y si tengo que reproducir eso en mis 20 métodos.

Comment: Te he añadido una explicación de lo que es un pool, me parece que te vendrá bien

Comment: Perfecto ya esta solucionado el problema y gracias por la explicación.